# How can I prevent a name error error in python?

Tags: python

When I run my program core.py (http://pastebin.com/kbzbBUYd) it returns:

File "core.py", line 47, in texto
    core.mail(numbersendlist, messagetext)
NameError: global name 'core' is not defined

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how I can stop this error?

If it helps, the "import carrier" line in core.py refers to carrier.py (http://pastebin.com/zP2RHbnr)

Comment: Your code does not have a line 47, so first off I would say you should synch your post with your code.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the pastebin page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting `NameError` Because there's no such name `core` defined in your code in either local or global scope. Create a `Core` object first before calling it's methods.

Also the indentation of `texto()` is probably wrong. You won't be able to use this function from rest of the module. If you want to use it from other parts of current module or from other modules, declare the function at module level or use the `@staticmethod` decorator to if you want to make it a static method of the class.

This should work.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import carrier

class Core:    
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        # code could be added here to auto load these from a file
        self.gmail_user = username
        self.gmail_pwd = password

# Send one text to one number
# TODO: send to multiple addresses

    def mail(self, to, text):
       msg = MIMEMultipart()
       msg['From'] = self.gmail_user
       msg['To'] = to
       msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

       mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.starttls()
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.login(self.gmail_user, self.gmail_pwd)
       mailServer.sendmail(self.gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
       # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
       mailServer.close()


def texto(sendtoaddress, messagetext):
    numbersendlist = []
    for number in sendtoaddress:
        numbersendlist.append(carrier.carriercheck(number))

    core = Core('username', 'password')
    for number in numbersendlist:
        core.mail(number, messagetext)

texto(['1112223333'], 'hi. this better work.')
```

Comment: That returns:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 42, in <module>
    texto(['1112223333'], 'hi. this better work.')
  File "new.py", line 40, in texto
    core.mail(numbersendlist, messagetext)
AttributeError: Core instance has no attribute 'mail'

Comment: Oh wait, some of my indentation was wrong. It instead produces: http://pastebin.com/npx3d8ci

Comment: Because you were sending the whole list to `mail()` in every iteration instead of a string. Fixed the code in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

`core` is not a name that you've defined, yet.  I expect that you intended to write something like

```
core = Core('username', 'password')
```

before calling `texto`?

Comment: should it just be "mail" instead of "core.mail" then? Because I tried that but got:
File "core.py", line 47, in texto
    mail(numbersendlist, messagetext)
NameError: global name 'mail' is not defined

I just want to run the "mail" function from within my texto function.